# Converting a burner over to NG

Tags: boil-equipment, burner

I'm in the process of converting my house from LP to NG and I'd like to have the plumbers run a drop for inside and outside by garage for my burner. Has anyone converted their LP burners to NG?  What should I be considering when setting this up?

I currently have a KAB6 bayou classic.  I have read the Brulosophy article on how he converted his KAB4 to use NG. http://brulosophy.com/2014/05/12/propane-to-natural-gas-conversion-best-investment-ive-made/  He used a simple turn valve regulator because his plumber said he had a lot of pressure coming into the house so he'd never have to worry about too low of pressure.

However, I think using an actual pressure regulator with a diaphragm and spring mechanism would be a safer investment in case my furnace kicks on.

Right now I am having the city run my NG piping and a plumber is coming out to install the lines inside the house so I don't know my gas pressure at this point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about home improvement more than about brewing.

Comment: He's talking about converting LP burners he uses for brewing to NG.  Its a brewing equipment question, how is that on topic?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in LP and NG burners is the jet. Propane use a very small small jet compared to NG. The propane jet can be drilled out to the size of the NG very easily.
https://youtu.be/Hl15-Zk5pmc

Propane burners run from 10-30 PSI, NG is only around 2 PSI.

I would definitely get an adjustable regulator. This gives you stable psi and gas adjustments all in one unit or a ball valve can be added to each burner.

If running 2-3 100k btu burners you may find that you need a .75-1 inch main line to keep them all going at once. Basically need to have .25 diameter per 100k btu per 100ft, but no less than 3/8". 1" pipe seems to feed a 400k btu pool heater 100ft from meter pretty good.